# How to execute a groovy script from a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins.

I have written a groovy script, which loads a token secret from an adjacent `config.properties` file.

What's the best way to execute this script in a groovy pipeline ?

What I think I need to do is:

- download that script from SCM
- change the token in config.properties (retrieved from the stored jenkins credentials)
- execute that script

I've seen various options :

- loading the script with `load()`, but this seems to be more dedicated to loading helper functions, whereas I only need to execute the whole script
- using shared libraries, but this seems to be more dedicated to code snippets reused across multiple jobs, which is not my case
- using `withGroovy {}`
- using `sh groovy`
- using a docker image that contains a groovy sdk

I tried these, and managed to get none of them to work (in part due to the extra-difficulty of retrieving the credential), so before I go any further I'd like to know what's the best option to proceed. For example, instead of trying to change the file config.properties in my pipeline to set the correct token, should I rather try to change my groovy script so that it takes the token from an environment variable ?

Thanks